# How to dynamically inject LinearLayout multiple times (Android)?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout

Okay, I made a XML Layout file containing a + and - button, and a textView, I was able to inject it into my LinearLayout by using:

```
    LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
    View injecterLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.newplayerlayout, myLayout, false);
    myLayout.addView(injecterLayout);
```

But I would like to be able to inject it multiple times, so I have several +, -, and textView's is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep using the same code to create new objecst? or am I missing something?

```
View injecterLayout;


    LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
    injecterLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.newplayerlayout, myLayout, false);
    myLayout.addView(injecterLayout);

    injecterLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.newplayerlayout, myLayout, false);
    myLayout.addView(injecterLayout);

    injecterLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.newplayerlayout, myLayout, false);
    myLayout.addView(injecterLayout);
```