# How to reuse same LinearLayout multiple times

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, reusability

I have created a tab application with three tabs. I am having a linearlayout which is common for three tabs. If I am add this linearlayout at the top of all the three tabs, the first tab dispalying the linearlayout. But I am getting the following error in second and third tab.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

If I am removing the child means, other tabs are affected. How to reuse the linearlayout more than once in java code, without the xml layout.

EDIT 1:

```
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ll.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    final AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "/6253334/dfp_example_ad");
    layout.addView(adView);  
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

I need to use this ad layout in all the three tabs.

EDIT 2:

I use the following code for creating the tab content.

```
public FrameLayout createTabContent()
  { 
    FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(sMainContext);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);    
    layout.setForegroundGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    layout.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);       
    mWebView=new WebView(sMainContext);
    mWebView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    LinearLayout adlayout = new LinearLayout(sMainContext);
    adLayout = (LinearLayout) (commonAdLayout);

    layout.addView(mWebView);
    layout.addView(adlayout);
    return layout;
}
```

commonLayout is created from the EDIT 1.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

if view exist use `removeView()` before adding view

or you can also try `removeAllViews()`

Comment: Yes, removing view in one tab affects the other tabs also. so, only asking, is there any way to reuse the same layout several times?

Comment: did you tried by first removing view and than adding it again !

Comment: Yes, adding and removing not affects other tab views.

Comment: I have defined layout as in my EDIT 1. I need to use this layout common for all the three tabs.

Comment: okay i reviewed that ! you can attach this with code where tab is defined !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35705/discussion-between-tarsem-and-karthick)

Comment: Actionbar tab, In the ontabselect method, i have loaded webview inside the tab. In the bottom of the tab content, I wish to add this ad view.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using same code(view) to add to your layout. You must create a new view or layout each time in your loop. See this link: [How to dynamically inject LinearLayout multiple times (Android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746748/how-to-dynamically-inject-linearlayout-multiple-times-android)